# Ubuntu 16.04 with linux 4.7-rc6 kernel

Tags: boot, usb, kernel, touchpad, elantech

I know (and I did it) how to make an USB key with Ubuntu 16.04 amd64 on it.

What I do need for a special hardware purpose is a kernel 4.7-rc6 on this USB key because only this will bring support for some special I2C Elan touchpad and I want to study the driver a bit.

How can I get the kernel updated to 4.7-rc6 in the USB key? Can I, for example, install a kernel from:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7-rc6-yakkety/
after booting the key?

Btw: The USB key does not boot correctly. One has to press TAB on the boot prompt to get the input option 'live....', which seems to be a known issue, but even with this it says 'not enough memory to boot the image' (the laptop has 2 GByte of RAM) and one has to say 'live mem=2000000000' to make it booting fine.

Comment: You can install many applications, but not really change kernel on the fly, you would have to reboot for that.

Comment: Of course I have to reboot. The question is; Can I update the kernel in the USB stick to 4.7-rc6 or is this somehow read only?

Comment: I booted the USB key, fetched the 4.7-rc6 kernel and installed it with `dpkg -i ....`. It went fine, but on boot it drops to a busybox shell which says that initramfs can't find a media containing a live file system.

Answer (score 0):

To close this thread: I've booted 16.04 from DVD and directed the install process to an USB key of 15.9 GByte which was visible for the installer as `sdb`. The installation went fine on the 3rd try. After rebooting the installed system from the USB key, I fetched and installed
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7-rc6-yakkety/linux-image-4.7.0-040700rc6-generic_4.7.0-040700rc6.201607040332_amd64.deb by just running

`sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb`.

After a reboot it says now:

```
$ uname -a
Linux tiny-ubuntu 4.7.0-040700rc6-generic #201607040332 SMP Mon Jul 4 07:34:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```